# Redux reducer for newsfeed and timeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Both the newsfeed and timeline have user posts. And I want to store each state so when the user changes tab it will stay where it was before.

Given this, is it ok if I have one reducer for each screen? NewsfeedScreen and TimelineScreen reducers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide them two like NewsfeedReducer and TimelineReducer as you mentioned. It's totally up to you, but keep in mind architecturing redux is pretty hard, you should step back and understand application requirements and communication between components. You cannot find an absolute answer for specific part of your application without any review of your codebase. Take a look at this useful blog post written by one the most popular js guy Eric Elliot [10 Tips for better redux architecture](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/10-tips-for-better-redux-architecture-69250425af44)